# Airflow - Send SMS notification on Failure

Tags: airflow, amazon-sns

Could anyone please let me know if there is a way to configure SMS notification through airflow. I am using AWS so if there is a way I can publish message to SNS then also it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on_failure_callback` and define whatever logic you require.
Since Airflow has `SnsPublishOperator` you can use it inside your python function.

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.sns import SnsPublishOperator

def on_failure_callback(context):
    op = SnsPublishOperator(
        task_id='failure',
        aws_conn_id=AWS_CONN_ID,
        target_arn=TARGET_ARN,
        message="Dag Failed",
        subject="Dag Failed",
    )  
    op.execute()

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 12, 05),
    on_failure_callback=on_failure_callback,
    default_args={'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback}
)
```

Comment: Thanks Elad, yes I am trying to implement this. However, we already have lots of job in production, this will require changes to all the jobs. is there a way I can have this configured without changing all the jobs

Comment: Can you share some code snippets so I can better understand the issue?

Comment: code sample would be pretty similar to yours.  Only question is rather than having this line `on_failure_callback=on_failure_callback,` in my 200 dags, can I place it some where globally and my all the dags automatically picks that up?

Comment: @GaurangShah It should be possible with [Cluster Policy](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#cluster-policy)  it allows you to overwrite tasks settings for all tasks in all dags.

Comment: yeah, I thought that.. however it doesn't see to work. would you mind taking a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224139/airflow-cluster-policy-is-not-getting-invoked