# Airflow Cluster Policy is not getting invoked

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to setup and understand custom policy. Not sure what I am doing wrong however, following this is not working.

**Airflow Version**: 1.10.10

**Expected result:**  it should throw exception if I try to run DAG with `default_owner`

**Actual Result:** no such exception

**/root/airflow/config/airflow_local_settings.py**

```py
class PolicyError(Exception):
    pass


def cluster_policy(task):
    print("task_instance_mutation_hook")
    raise PolicyError


def task_instance_mutation_hook(ti):
    print("task_instance_mutation_hook")
    raise PolicyError
```

- /root/airflow/config/airflow_local_settings.pyc file is being created so I know this file is being processed by airflow.
- if there is any compilation error in this file all my dags fails. however not with above file.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available from 1.10.12 version only.